# Cannot connect multiple components using redux in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, jsx

I am not able to understand how to connect two different components with the `redux` store.

Following is what I tried:

View.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';

export default ({counter,actions:{ incrementCounter}}) => (
<View>
<Text>Hello from page 1</Text>
<Button
  title='Go to page 2'
  onPress={() => Actions.page2({})}
/>
<Button
  title='Go to page 3'
  onPress={() => Actions.page3({})}
/>
<Button
  title='INCREMENT'
  onPress={() => incrementCounter()}
/>
<Text>{counter}</Text>
```

);

Page2.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
 View,
 Text,
 Button,
} from 'react-native';

import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { incrementCounter } from '../actions';

export default ({counter,actions:{ incrementCounter}}) => (
  <View>
    <Text>Hello from page2</Text>
    <Button 
      title='Go to Page 1'
      onPress={() => Actions.page1({})} />
    <Button 
      title='Go to Page 3'
      onPress={() => Actions.page3({})} />

    <Button
     title='Increment'
     onPress={() => incrementCounter()}
    />
  <Text>{counter}</Text>
  </View>

);
```

index.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {View ,div} from 'react-native';

import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

import Page1 from './View'
import Page2 from '../Page2'
import * as actionCreators from '../../actions';


class AllComp extends Component{
 render(){
     const {counter, actions} = this.props;
     return(
      <View>
       <Page1 counter={counter} actions={actions} />
       <Page2 counter={counter} actions={actions}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    counter:state.counter,
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return{
    actions: bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(AllComp);
```

The output I received after running the code is a bit weird.

It display the contents of both the pages (View.js and Page2.js) in the same page itself.

I read that to connect multiple components I have to wrap those components into one and I did the same thing. But as I said earlier the output was a bit weird.

Comment: What is the wierdness?

Comment: That it displays the contents of both the pages in the same page. But it shouldn't have. As View.js page has a button named page 2 that routes us to page 2. But whats happening is that the data in page 2 is being displayed in view.js page itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a single view including two pages,

```
  <View>
   <Page1 counter={counter} actions={actions} />
   <Page2 counter={counter} actions={actions}/>
  </View>
```

This is the reason both of your pages are being displayed in the same screen.
`React-native-router-flux` [documentation](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md) states that the routes should be specified in your `App.js` as,

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Stack key="root">
      <Scene key="page1" component={Page1} title="Page 1"/>
      <Scene key="page1" component={Page2} title="Page 2"/>
    </Stack>
  </Router>
);
```

To connect multiple component to redux you dont have to wrap them in same component instead you have to `connect` them to redux using the following functions in which ever component you have to connect.

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    counter:state.counter,
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return{
    actions: bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Page1);
```